# Reputation tab bug: Single event duplicated arbitrary amount of times

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-history

I open up my reputation tab today, and this is what I see:

[image]

Comment: Little bit of experimentation (read, switching between Post and Time) and it seems like the *number of events* is the same. If you had two upvotes and a downvote, that's three events. However, in Time view all three event slots shows *one* of those repeated. I'm not even sure what the pattern is - it doesn't seem to be the first or the last. Or any particular one.

Comment: @VLAZ Okay, but can you explain [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376538/773001)? XD

Comment: @VLAZ The post seems to be a +1/-0

Comment: @AnnZen yes - easy: It's broken.

Comment: I still prefer this version to the previous iteration where I could see about three reputation changes on a fullHD screen thanks to the huge list items.

Comment: I witness a similar image on mine too, as if the records `row_number(part by day ordered by time desc) = 1` were picked :)

Comment: Curious if there's a reason you're posting very similar questions on multiple sites rather than picking one? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376538/reputation-tab-shows-30-40-50-60-70-80-90-100-110-each-as-an-i We are aware there's an issue and are working on it - we appreciate the report but it's helpful if you can pick one place to report something rather than posting very similar reports in multiple places. :)

Comment: @Catija Well, I saw this bug here, so I reported it, then I decided to check Meta if it has the same bug. To my surprise, it's [even more peculiar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416176/reputation-tab-bug-single-event-duplicated-arbitrary-amount-of-times?noredirect=1#comment896240_416176) in MSE!

Comment: I mean, the fact that it's borked is the same everywhere. The specifics of it will depend on the reputation changes you've had. You could have just edited this one instead of posting on MSE, too.

Comment: @Catija Okay, I understand. Thanks for letting me know, I'll do just that the next time! But even so, other users posted the same thing on MSE after mine, so at least now they have a proper dupe target, no? ;)

Comment: @Catija Thinking it over, and I should have thought of it at that time, I should've deleted this after finding the bug on MSE. I hope it's not too late, will it be okay to delete this now? Thanks again!

Comment: There is no rule or requirement to not post on MSO when reporting on MSE -